# Conditions for chain rule for Gateaux derivatives

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

Let $X,Y,Z$ be locally convex topological vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ (not necessarily Banach), $D_X \subseteq X$, $D_Y \subseteq Y$ and let $f \colon D_X \to D_Y$, $g \colon D_Y \to Z$. Let us assume that $f$ is Gateaux-differentiable in some $x \in D_X$ and $g$ is Gateaux-differentiable in $f(x)$.

Which are the least well-known additional conditions for the chain rule to hold? By the chain rule I mean the assertion that $g \circ f$ is Gateaux-differentiable and $\mathrm d(g \circ f)(x;\cdot) = \mathrm d g(f(x);\mathrm d f(x;\cdot))$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative#Properties) says that continuity of the derivatives of $f$ and $g$ is required, but it does not specify whether this means that only $\mathrm df \colon D_X \times X \to Y$ should be continuous or, more than that, $x \mapsto \mathrm df(x,\cdot) \in L(X,Y)$ should be continuous (and, of course, the same for $g$).

And is it generally assumed that $D_X$ and $D_Y$ are open or is it enough to know that they are neighborhoods of $x$ and $f(x)$?

Please also help me to find a citable reference. I looked into some books, but have not found this chain rule.

This question has also been posted on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4488066/395241) a few days ago, but got no answers so far.

Comment: The most general theorem on the chain rule for functionals I aware of is the one given by Kriegl and Michor's *[The convenient setting of global analysis](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/apbookh-ams.pdf)*, Mathematical Surveys and Monographs. 53. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). x, 618 p. (1997), [MR1471480](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1471480), [Zbl 0889.58001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0889.58001). It is precisely theorem 3.18 at page 33: be it noted thai it is stated in therm of functional derivatives, thus in a possibly more general setup.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri This theorem is very specific since it requires $f$ and $g$ to be even $C^\infty$. So it does not really answer my question which notion of continuous differentiability is needed.

Answer (score 4):

The general (necessary and sufficient) condition for the chain rule to hold at the given pair of points $x$ and $y=f(x)$ is that $g$ be Hadamard (also called compactly, or quasi-) differentiable at $y$. Generally the domains are assumed open but (almost trivially) one can loosen this to requiring ${\rm dom\,}f$ be "starlike" at $x$ and ${\rm dom\,}g$ be "sequentially tangential" at $y$. Here being "starlike" means that for every $u$ in $X$ there be $\delta\in\mathbb R^+$ such that $x+tu\in{\rm dom\,}f$ holds for $|t|<\delta$, and "sequentially tangential" means that for any sequences $v_n\to v$ in $Y$ and $t_n\to 0$ there is $n_0$ such that $y+t_nv_n\in{\rm dom\,}g$ holds for $n_0\le n$. For the details in the case of open domains see Yamamuro's *Differential Calculus in Topological Linear Spaces*, Springer LNM 374 (1974) 1.2.7, pp. 9−13. These result are already in Averbukh and Smolyanov "The various definitions of the derivative in linear topological spaces" *Russian Math. Surveys* **23** 4 (1968) 67−113 and Sova "General theory of differentiability in linear topological spaces" *Czech. Math. J.* **14** (1964) 485−508.

Comment: Does that mean that my Wikipedia link is wrong and continuous Gateaux differentiability in the sense that $x\mapsto \mathrm d f(x,\cdot) \in L(X,Y)$ is continuous (and the same for $g$) is not sufficient? Or does Hadamard follow from this? If yes, does Hadamard also follow from the weak continuity condition ($\mathrm df\colon D_X \times X \to Y$ continuous)?

Comment: I don't see your Wikipedia link saying anything **precise** about the *derivative* ${\rm D\,}f=f':X\to{\mathcal L\,}(X,Y)$ being continuous. Instead, it speaks about the *variation* ${\rm\delta\,}f:(x,u)\mapsto{\rm\delta\,}f(x,u)=f'(x)u$ being continuous but this is not needed for the chain rule to hold. Hadamard differentiability of $g$ at $y=f(x)$ follows (by the mean value theorem) if one assumes that the variation ${\rm\delta\,}g$ is continuous. (cont.)

Comment: Likewise, it follows from the derivative ${\rm D\,}g=g'$ being continuous $Y\to L={\mathcal L\,}(Y,Z)$ provided that $L$ is equipped with a vector topology that is at least as strong as the topology of uniform convergence on sequentially compact sets in $Y$.

Comment: AND, for comprehension, **generally** there is no implication [ ${\rm D\,}f$ continuous ${}\Rightarrow{\delta\,}f$ continuous ] nor [ ${\delta\,}f$ continuous ${}\Rightarrow{\rm D\,}f$ continuous ] in the setting of maps between topological vector spaces. In the setting of maps between *convergence vector spaces* there is, namely, that of Bastiani's, *J. Anal. Math.*, 1964.

Comment: @TaQ May you give more details on the fact that the continuity of variation implies Hadamard differentiability? I am not sure how to apply the mean value theorem for vector-valued function.

Comment: @John See 1.4.2 on page 18 in Yamamuro's *Differential Calculus in Topological Linear Spaces*, Springer LNM 374.